# no console output in eclipse C/C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, console

I am trying to brush up on my C++ Skills, which I haven't used since college. Apparently I am so rusty, that I can't even get a normal Hello World to run: When I open the Hello World Template and Build it, it compiles just fine, but when I run it, there's no output on the console.

This seems to be a known bug that appeared around 2010, but I don't think it has never been fixed in 4 years. To make it work, so far I have tried: Uninstalling the 64-Bit Versions and installing the 32-Bit versions and added C:\cygwin\bin to my PATH Variable. Also I have added

```
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

But it tells me, it can't resolve stevbuf. What do I need to include, to make this work?

I tested executing the program in the console, which worked just fine, and I also Added a beep, which didn't play in eclipse, but worked just fine in the console.

Here's the software versions I use:
Windows 7 64-Bit
Cygwin 32-Bit 2.850

Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers Version: Kepler Service Release 2
Build id: 20140224-0627

What else could I test?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Best regards,
Pete

Comment: Did you include `<cstdio>`? See the documentation over [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/setvbuf/) (upper right corner)

Comment: I included `<stdio.h>` but there's still no console output. Thanks for the input, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the past couple of days I have been using the command line to run my programs. However, today I noticed, that tere is an Output now in the console in Eclipse.

I'm not sure which of the things I tried did the trick, but it wasn't adding:

```
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

I tried commenting it out and it kept working.